# What determines the turn-order in combat?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

Based on my limited experience with the demo of EOIV and EOU I'm aware that the order that party members and enemies take actions in combat is determined by some hidden value. Turn-Order has been mentioned by some skills, and I recall reading something in EOIV that spells reduce turn-order since they take time to cast. I'm looking for more details on what effects turn-order, along with how it actually works (i.e Do certain classes get a bonus to turn-order? Do certain weapons? et cetera).

What determines the turn-order in combat, and what can influences the turn-order?

Answer (score 2):

I won't make an exhaustive list of what can influence turn order, but the primary factor is agility. The higher a characters agility, the earlier in the turn they attack.
The second factor is equipment worn, as follows:

> Shield: -2 speed Heavy Armor: -2 speed Medium Armor: -1 speed Light
>   Armor: +2 speed Gloves: +1 speed Shoes: +4 speed Accessories and helms
>   are neutral.
>
> Gunblade: -4 speed Hammers: -3 speed Swords: -2 speed Thrusting
>   Swords: +2 speed Katanas: +2 speed Daggers: +3 speed Bows and staves
>   are neutral.

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997793-etrian-odyssey-iv-legends-of-the-titan/65578678

Comment: Are you sure EO4 uses the same mechanics as EO:MG? Also, is that number a straight additive for equipment, such that a katana is essentially worth 2 points of agility when it comes to speed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the mechanics are the same, and I am pretty sure the numbers are just a modifier to agility, yes.

Comment: As a note, boots/daggers/rapiers tend to be the gear that most consistently increases action speed throughout the series, while heavy armour most consistently decreases it.